# can't improve FID for my full amp website

Tags: amp-html

I have a full amp website ([this page](https://prayer-time.uk/prayer-times-london-259-en) for example). I did implement these optimisation to reduce the time of FID (First Input Delay) :

1. Use of the amp optimizer (php implementation)
2. push of critic javascript (h2 is activated in the server)

but I still have an **FID of 250ms**. How can I do to get the FID under 100 ms ?

PS: the others CORS metric are ok for the website.

Comment: Hi, you should take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on StackOverflow, explaining how to properly ask a question. The community is here to help you, but you definitely need to provide more details to help us answer your question :)

Comment: I did my best to add aditional information. thank you for the advise